# How to implement "People also viewed the following products..." feature?

Tags: xdb

I need to implement something similar to Amazon's product suggestions on the product details page. For example, if I am on a product details page of item A, I need to display "People also viewed the following products" section which list Items X , Y, Z

I have the products in Sitecore as Items.

How do I implement this feature using xDb? I need to track every user's activity and recommend top 5 products based on the current product that the user is viewing.

Any suggestions?